# How to check a github file in text version with php

Tags: php, github

My question is simple!
I could see how a github file on  text in mode?
I just need to compare the contained of github file.

Would you know how to do with php?

Comment: While your question is indeed simple, I fail to understand it. Do you mean you want to get the raw contents of a file in github from a php script ?

Comment: @SirDarius yes! I am looking for a way to recover a file contained github, not by any means import (get file content, curl ....) I just want to know how to view a file in text (from github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github has pretty straightforward urls when it comes to raw files. See this example:

> https://raw.github.com/libgit2/libgit2/development/CMakeLists.txt

So as long as you know the path to a file in a github project, you can use the special `raw.github.com` hostname, and read the contents from PHP.

Comment: Oooh! Two hours that I was looking for! big thank you @SirDarius =)