# Check if there is a newer version of my local file in Github, with R

Tags: r, git, github, download

In short: I need to get the date of last change in a file hosted on Github.

In long: given that in Github I have a file (an R workspace) that once in a while is updated, I would like to create a function in R that checks if my local file is older than the one in the repo (if you're curious, my motivation is exposed at the end of this post). [This is the file](https://github.com/jumanbar/Curso-R/blob/master/ejercicios-de-programacion/rep-3/datos) I'm talking about.

In principle it should be somewhat easy, since every file has a [history page](https://github.com/jumanbar/Curso-R/commits/master/ejercicios-de-programacion/rep-3/datos) associated with it, but my knowledge is far too poor to know what to do with this. Also, [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865946/how-to-check-a-github-file-in-text-version-with-php) seems to hint at some way of doing what I want using php, but that's terra incognita for me really, so I don't know if it could help in any way.

So, as I said in the short version of this post, I need to find a way to retrieve the date of the last commit for this file. I can find some way to compare it to the commit date of my local file afterwards.

Thanks in advance,
Juan

*motivation*: I'm working in a an online course in R basics which uses a system for self-checking if solutions of exercises are correct (i.e.: students can check their results instantly). This system uses a file with functions and data that is regularly updated because I often find bugs and new problems. So my goal is to have a function to tell the students if there is a newer file available. It would also be neat to find a way to download it and replace the older, but that is secondary now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is to keep the git-time of the download. The solution below sets the file time to the Git date after each download for the next check.

```
library(RCurl)
library(rjson)
destination = "datos" # assume current directory
repo = "https://api.github.com/repos/jumanbar/Curso-R/"
path = "ejercicios-de-programacion/rep-3/datos"
myopts = curlOptions(useragent="whatever",ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)

d = fromJSON(getURL(paste0(repo,"commits?path=",path),
                useragent="whatever",ssl.verifypeer=FALSE))[[1]]
gitDate  = as.POSIXct(d$commit$author$date)
MustDownload = !file.exists(destination) |  file.info(destination)$mtime > gitDate
if (MustDownload){
  url = d$url
  commit = fromJSON(getURL(url, .opts=myopts))
  files = unlist(lapply(commit$files,"[[","filename"))
  rawfile = commit$files[[which(files==path)]]$raw_url
  download.file(rawfile,destination,quiet=TRUE)
  Sys.setFileTime(destination,gitDate)
  print("File was downloaded")
}
```

It looks like from R the useragent and ssl.verifypeer is required; works without from the command line. If you are security-conscious, there is documentation on that subject floating around, but I took the easy path to commit.

Comment: This is wonderful thank you! I still cannot get to download the file from R and I really don't know what to make of the `useragent` or `ssl.verifypeer` options. For the former I've tried "Mozilla/5.0" to no avail. When the `download.file` is run I get "download had nonzero exit status" using `method="wget"` or `"curl"` and "URL scheme not supported" (translated from spanish). Anyway, this is what I was hopping for.

Comment: Try to put the string from rawfile into the browser, and check if you can download it that way when logged in to github.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need a local clone of the github repo. Forgetting language specifics of R for the moment (I don't know R), in git you can get the most recent date in a number of ways through `git log`. From the `git log` help file (`git help log`), under the Placeholders section:

```
%cd: committer date
%cD: committer date, RFC2822 style
%cr: committer date, relative
%ct: committer date, UNIX timestamp
%ci: committer date, ISO 8601 format
```

You can retrieve the UNIX timestamp (seconds since the start of January 1st, 1970 - very easily comparable) of the most recent commit for your file, starting from the project root, with the following `git log` command:

```
git log --format=%ct -1 -- ejercicios-de-programacion/rep-3/datos
```

That returns a number, e.g. 1368691710, but you can use the other formats listed as well.

Now you just need to find a way to make this system call from R, with your project root as the working directory. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745886/r-and-system-calls) may help (but again, I don't R).

Comment: This would certainly work in my computer but not in others (students PCs), so is not a viable solution in this case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make use of the "git status" command (which tells you if there are new commits) im combination with cronjobs. But you need a local clone for this. And I never tried to use the output of the command inside a cronjob.

Comment: If there are new commits in the remote that you haven't fetched, `git status` won't tell you. You have to `git fetch` first.